# I'm getting this error of 'cannot find .svg file in the directory' while it was there in the directory

Tags: graphics, luatex, paths, svg, dvisvgm

```
"errorSummary": {
            "error": [
                "! Package svg Error: File `emptystar.svg' is missing.\n",
                "! Package svg Error: File `emptystar.svg' is missing.\n",
                "! Package svg Error: File `emptystar.svg' is missing.\n",
                "! Package svg Error: File `emptystar.svg' is missing.\n",
                "! Package svg Error: File `emptystar.svg' is missing.\n"
            ],
Above is error
```

below is the function snippet

```
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{svg}
\svgpath{{services/pdf_generator/libs/common-utils/}}

\begin{luacode*}
function generateRatingMarker(rating)
  local rating = tonumber(rating)
  
  -- Limit the rating to the range [0, 5]
  if rating > 5 then
    rating = 5
  elseif rating < 0 then
    rating = 0
  end

  -- Print color SVG images
  for i = 1, rating do
    tex.print("\\includesvg{emptystar}") -- Corrected path and removed extra slashes
  end

  -- Print empty SVG images
  for i = rating + 1, 5 do
    tex.print("\\includesvg{emptystar}") -- Corrected path and removed extra slashes
  end
end
```

and believe me I have those emptystar.svg in the same folder I specified above

Comment: is `services/pdf_generator/libs/common-utils/` a subfolder of the folder where you start the compilation?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, this issue is not related to not finding the file  but was caused by not enabling `escape shell command`.